# Ejecutar una función al terminar otra jQuery

Tags: jquery, funciones, dom

Necesito ejecutar una función después de que termine otra función:

la primera función lo que hace es crear "X" numero de tablas lo cual esto tarda un determinado tiempo aveces mas aveces menos  dependiendo los datos que contenga el arreglo

```
$("#consultar").click(function(){
  // código de la función
});
```

una ves que termine esa función que se ejecute la otra función...

> ejemplo de la primera función:

```js
$("#consultar").click(function(){
$("#tablas").empty();
      var datos = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

      var tabla='';
      $(datos).each(function(i,e){
        tabla +='<table id="'+e+'" class="table"><thead><tr><td colspan="2"><center>'+e+'</center></td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Ejemplo1</td><td>122</td></tr><tr><td>Ejemplo1</td><td>122</td></tr><tr><td>Ejemplo1</td><td>122</td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><td>Prueba</td><td></td></tr></tfoot></table><br>';
      });
      $("#tablas").append(tabla);
});



//otra funcion

function suma(){
  var total=0;
  $("#1 tr").find('td:eq(1)').each(function () {
      valor = $(this).html();
      total +=+valor
   });

   $("#1").text(parseFloat(total).toFixed(3));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id="consultar" type="botton" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:10px; float: right; margin-right: 1%;">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Consultar
        </button>
<div id="tablas"></div>
```

> una ves creadas las tablas y que termine esa función que se ejecute la
>   segunda función. no son las originales pero algo así es lo que intento hacer

Comment: aun sigues teniendo problemas con esta pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#consultar").click(function(){
  // Tu código...
  suma();
}
```